# How to get the text from FormTextBox?

Tags: jquery, razor

I have the code:

```
<div class="col-left">
                @FormTextBox("Message:", Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "required-form-control" }))
</div>
```

Now I want to modify the text then save it. So I added a button to do it via ajax call.
My question is how to get it in js side?

**EDIT:**
The custom template is:

```
@helper FormTextBox(string labelText, MvcHtmlString input)
{
  // divs
}
```

Comment: just need to know which is the id of the input. and in the javascript with document.getElementById('yourid').value; can obtain the value typed in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal circumstances the razor engine would generate the following html when using @Html.TextAreaFor

```
<textarea class="required-form-control" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="2"></textarea>
```

You would then be able to access the value of that element in jquery like so:

```
var check = $('#Message').val();
alert(check);
```

It does appear that you (or team member have created a custom display template (@FormTextBox) so your rendered html output may be different than the standard element output for the text area. If it does not render the id like I have shown in html then edit your question to include the html generated by razor and we can go from there.

Comment: @Bigeyes thanks for the updated question. So what we need to find out is what html is generated after razor gets done rendering it (since jquery doesn't even come into play until after razor does its thing) So run your project, open it in chrome, right click the text area on the page and select the "inspect element" option. once you know the ID attribute for that specific element then you can tell jquery what to fetch. If you would like then copy the html in your question and i can help you locate your needed ID

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<div class="col-left">
    @FormTextBox("Message:", Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "required-form-control", id = "Message" }))
</div>
```

And then use the id `Message` in your jQuery selector